# Catch json.net serialization errors

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm working on a web api using dotnet core 2.2 and we want to catch serialization exception and return a 400 badRequest to distinguish from the validation errors 422UnprocessableEntity. We tried to create  an exception handler

```
public void JsonSerializerExceptionHandler(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        var errorContext = args.ErrorContext;
        if (errorContext == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var error = errorContext.Error;
        throw new SerializationException(error.Message, error.InnerException);
    }
```

but when it throw it throw an other Exception of type InvalidOperationException with message

> Current error context error is different to requested error.

We tried different approach but can't find a solution. Can someone help?

Comment: Im unsure why you are trying to achieve this. I would just wrap my serialization code in a try catch and if you are looking for serialization errors just add a specific catch block for that. You can go as far as writing a middleware that specifically catches these anywhere in the MVC layer.

Comment: We are trying to achieve this because it is a request from the client, Json.net does not throw exceptions  by itself, if I remove the last line it doesn't throw at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution will be useful for somebody.
I need to catch JSON.NET serialization or deserialization exception and handle it in my .NET Core middleware.

#### Add rethrow json.net exception in JSON.NET SerializerSettings

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {


    //your options here
 

    options.SerializerSettings.Error += (sender, args) => throw args.ErrorContext.Error;

});
```

#### Add catch on middleware handler and override JsonSerializationException:

```
if (exception is JsonSerializationException)
{
    var exceptionMessage = exception.InnerException != null ? 
       exception.InnerException.Message : exception.Message;

    exception = new BadRequestException(ApiErrorCode.InvalidResourceModel,
      exceptionMessage);
}
```

Comment: I have occasionally hit issues where an action parameter was null. They are frustrating to debug, but so far have been very straight-forward.  This one was very difficult, so I went in search of info on how to see deserialization error details.  This post was VERY useful, thank you!  Upvoted.