# How do I catch validation error in C# WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, restsharp

I have a C# Web API. It has a controller which has a POST method in it. The model class I pass has some data annotations (e.g. `Required`, `MaxLength`, etc).

I am calling it from a client using RestSharp.

Any time there is some kind of problem, I just get a generic error message on the client side:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PDS.Core.Types.ResponseDtos.ErrorCode]....

Wouldn't be a problem, but on the server side when I put a breakpoint into the method it doesn't hit the breakpoint. So I am assuming the error is being thrown by the validation (or something else).

So my question is, how do I find out what the problem is? I can't debug the code since it's not hitting the breakpoint. Is there some kind of interceptor I can put on the server side so I can at least see some kind of error message?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557846/catch-json-net-serialization-errors

Comment: Depending on the framework version search for turning off automatic (400 BadRequest) responses.

Comment: As error message showing that issue with input request; I don't think we need to debug this issue. Please check that whether the client is passing the input request as expected. If you want debug the issue at controller you could use the filter: SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter  as explained below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 2.1 or later, Web API controllers using [ApiController] attribute, model state validation occurs automatically.

To turn off this filter, add this to your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0